# Starting section zoom *before* specific animations on slide

Tags: powerpoint

Section zoom seems to always start last on a PPT slide. How can I start it somewhere between several animations? (given that I don't have touch screen our mouse at the presentation to directly click on it)

Answer (score 0):

You can start a section zoom at any time during an animation sequence. Click on the section thumbnail you want to zoom to. By default, the home slide is reset to the beginning of the animation sequences, so the animations you already ran before zooming will run again.

To avoid this, create a duplicate of the home slide, but place it after the section to which you zoomed. On the Zoom Tools tab, uncheck **Return to Zoom**, so the presentation doesn't jump back. Include only the animations you want to run after the zoom.